# Converting a transitive dependency into a compileOnly dependency

Tags: gradle, osgi, dependency-management, bnd

I am trying to use OSGI to allow me to use two different versions of a transitive dependency. The plan is that one version (the newer version) will be hidden away inside an OSGI bundle, the other will be on the runtime classpath as normal.

I have built the bundle jar using Gradle (with the Groovy DSL), but the problem is its associated runtime dependencies are wrong - it brings along the newer version, which is supposed to be hidden inside the bundle. This is still true when I do, in the `build.gradle` file:

```
compileOnly deps.diffx
runtimeOnly(deps.diffx) {
    exclude group: 'com.propensive', module: 'magnolia_' + versions.scala_v
}
```

If I examine the dependencies with the Gradle `dependencies` task, it shows that magnolia is excluded from the `runtimeOnly` configuration, as expected - but is *not* excluded from the `runtimeClasspath` configuration.

If I then use `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency magnolia_2.12 --configuration runtime` to try to find out where this dependency is coming from, it tells me that the newer version is coming from `runtimeClasspath` depending on `diffx`, and this is selected via conflict resolution. Well thanks - I already knew that. The question is, *why* is my exclusion not being applied to the derived configuration?

Basically I want to do the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918568/gradle-exclude-a-dependency-for-a-configuration-but-not-for-an-inheriting-con).

I also tried constraint versions, but they exhibited the same problem:

```
compileOnly deps.diffx
runtimeOnly(deps.diffx) {
    constraints {
        implementation('com.propensive:magnolia_' + versions.scala_v + ':0.10.0') {
            because 'this version is required by our other dependencies'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/dependency_management.html):

> On the upside, Gradle’s exclude handling is, in contrast to Maven, taking the whole dependency graph into account. So if there are multiple dependencies on a library, excludes are only exercised if all dependencies agree on them. For example, if we add opencsv as another dependency to our project above, which also depends on commons-beanutils, commons-collection is no longer excluded as opencsv itself does not exclude it.

So instead, we can use a [dependency resolve rule](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/resolution_rules.html):

```
def magnoliaVersion = '0.10.0'

configurations.runtimeClasspath {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.propensive' && details.requested.name.startsWith("magnolia_") && details.requested.version != magnoliaVersion) {
            details.useVersion magnoliaVersion
            details.because 'this version is required by our other dependencies'
        }
    }
}
```

and then change the dependency back to a simple, single `implementation` one:

```
implementation deps.diffx
```

Unfortunately, as the documentation notes, this resolve rule isn't published, so it has to be applied again in any dependent Gradle modules.